# Pandas UDF Method __getstate__([]) does not exist error

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

I'm using pyspark 2.4.1 and am trying to write a simple function with Pandas UDF shown below. Basically create a new columns and assigning string values based on `df.x=='a'` and `df.y=='t'`. However, I keep getting `Method __getstate__([]) does not exist` error. Here are 2 ways I tried with Pandas UDF and not sure what other ways to write it:

**data**

```
x = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])
y = pd.Series(['t','t','t'])

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({"x":x,"y":y}))
df.show()
```

```
+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
|  a|  t|
|  b|  t|
|  c|  t|
+---+---+
```

**Attempt 1:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

import pandas as pd

@pandas_udf(StringType(), PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def test_fun(x: str, y: str) -> pd.Series:
    import os
    os.environ["ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT"] = "1"
    if x.values=='a' and y.values=='t':
        return z == 'ok'
    else:
        return z == "None"
    return pd.Series(z)
```

```
df.withColumn('test',test_fun(col("x"),col("y"))).show()
```

**Attempt 2**

```
def test_func(df):
    @pandas_udf(StringType(), PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
    def test(x: str, y: str) -> pd.Series:
        import os
        os.environ["ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT"] = "1"
        if x.values=='a' and y.values=='t':
            return z == 'ok'
        else:
            return z == "None"
        return pd.Series(z) 
     
    return df.withColumn('test', test(col('x'),col('y')))
```

```
test_func(df)
```

Both gave me the same error message:

```
...py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling t.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm quite new to spark and read many threads with similar problems but couldn't figure out the correct way to modify it.

Comment: Are you really looking for an udf? You can do `df.withColumn("New",F.when((F.col("x")=="a") & (F.col("y")=="t"),"ok")).show()` I think

Comment: `z` is not defined in the udf

Comment: I need to use pandas_udf instead of when().otherwise() for more complex logic, I'm using this example to test out how to make it work. I also tried `@pandas_udf(StringType(), PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def test_fun(x: str, y: str) -> pd.Series:
    import os
    os.environ["ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT"] = "1"
    if x.values=='a' and y.values=='t':
        return 'ok'
    else:
        return 'None'`. Got error`RuntimeError: Result vector from pandas_udf was not the required length: expected 1, got 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with attempt 1 and I am sure this would work with attempt 2 as well.

In your udf, you are returning 3 times and the way it is returned, z is not defined before.

Following function worked for me on spark 2.4.7 and pyarrow==0.13.0

```
@pandas_udf(StringType(), PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def test_fun(x: str, y: str) -> pd.Series:
    if x.values=='a' and y.values=='t':
        z = 'ok'
    else:
        z = "None"
    return pd.Series(z)
```

z should be defined in if-else check and then returned.

Comment: Allthough I landed on this question as I'm facing the same error of (__getstate__([]) due to some other reason

Comment: Here is why one can get error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59119213/pyspark-best-alternative-for-using-spark-sql-df-withing-a-udf

Comment: I can mostly be certain that the reason my code didn't work was because pyspark version and pyarrow setting in the company's VM. Thanks for answering